# Add blank entry to ListBox and that entry should be editable

Tags: c#, wpf, insert, listboxitem

How to add blank entry at the top of the listbox and that entry should be editable.

I wrote following code which is adding blank entry but it doesn't allow me to edit. How should I make it editable?

```
private void CustomButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem itm = new ListBoxItem();
        itm.Content = "";

        listBox1.Items.Insert(0,itm);
    }
```

Inside my listBox, I've following things,

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StartTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StopTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="71"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ProjectNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="130"/>  
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Editable DataTemplate -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditableDataTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
                <!--<ComboBox x:Name="ClientComboBox" SelectionChanged="ClientComboBoxChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=clientList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name" SelectedItem="{Binding ClientNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="145"/>-->
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StartTimeBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StopTimeBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="130"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="ProjectComboBox" SelectionChanged="ProjectComboBoxChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=projectList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name"  SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Width="71" Background="Yellow" BorderThickness="0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>!
```

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Why not use DataGrid? I think ListBox is ment to be only for showing, not editing.

Comment: I've textboxes for my listBox which are binded to some lists so after clicking button, values comes automatically. Now I want to manually enter values there.

Comment: Show your `XAML` of `ListBox/ListBoxItem`. Do you use the `Style/Template`?

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev I used DataTemplates. But, I want to manually add entries in those textboxes. On button click, the above code generates blank entry but doesn't allow to edit.

Comment: Just because the element in the `DataTemplate` do not get access. Assign a name to each `TextBox` and use the `FindChild<>` function, which uses `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()`. Is full of examples, [one](http://borsukmsdcrm.blogspot.ru/2011/04/wpf-visualtreehelper-findchild.html). Get the right `TextBox`, and set your text like that: `MyTextBox.Text = "TestText";`.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev Can you please show that in answer?

Comment: I want to write text at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox` is not editable. You can create a `textbox` and put your value in that, after that assign that value to `listboxitem`.

The other option is to use the `DataGridView` (as mentioned in the comments). It allows editing.

Comment: I've textBoxes in my listBox which are binded to some list. Now I want to write values for textboxes manually.

Comment: @Dinesh Make your `textbox` editable `ReadOnly = "true"` edit in xml code

Comment: "ReadOnly" is inaccessible.

Comment: Sorry, `ReadOnly` needs to be `false`. And kindly share the image of your listbox

Comment: Now, you can see image of my listBox window.